# Ruby Shoes verification of entry

Tags: ruby

How can I disallow enter any other characters without numbers in Shoes GUI?

```
Shoes.app(resizable: false) do

  background white..blue
  @t = 0
  tab = []
  0.upto(9) {|i| tab.push(String(i))}

  @b = edit_line(left: 120, top: 10) do
    if @b.text != "" and tab.include?(@b.text)
      keypress do |k|
        if k == "\n"
          @av.text = @av.text.to_i + @b.text.to_i
          @b.text = ""
          @t = @t + 1
          @show.text = "Average: " + (@av.text.to_i / @t).to_s
        end
      end
    end
  end

  @d = flow(left: 325, top: 10) do
    @av = para strong("Average")
    @show = para strong("Show!")
  end

end
```

I tried to allow to add numbers and compute average only when "tab" contains any character we typed in "edit_line", but the program completely stopped correct working when I added this one:

```
and tab.include?(@b.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  =~ operator to tests a string against a regular expression:

```
def valid?(text)
  text =~ /^[0-9]+/ ? true : false
end
```

Usage:

```
   if valid?("ssd11") # return false
     #do something
```

Comment: Is it possible to change this pattern that allow only numbers?